transaction error execution reverted
I hope someone can help. I bridged some ETH over to the TON network via dedust.
I had issues claiming the transaction, which I have now managed to do. However, recipient’s address hasn't got funded.
Using my Ethereum address, when I checked on Etherscan, it’s showing:
"Although one or more Error Occurred [execution reverted] Contract Execution Completed"

When I toggle on the ADVANCED MODE in the internal transactions, I can see that 1 of the 5 internal transactions is having error:

What does this mean and how can I get my funds back?
Here is the transaction hash:
0x57755e964b9a5dcda1f68083d0fdd0c77443ba5865b648343d284f38c4fae9d2
Thanks in advance, for any advice.

The transaction was successful, the usdt arrived at its destination as far as ethereum is concerned. The tokens arrived at and are locked in the bridge.. The revert was for something called in a try/catch .. try IWrappedJetton(token).isWrappedJetton()... catch {return false;}, but didn't effect the safeTransferFrom, that was successful. Notice everyone else's deposits include the same error.. Have you looked at the address you were bridging it to, with an explorer for the chain you bridged it to?

I would also ask for some clarity. 1 you say you bridged over ETH, but the value sent with the hash you showed is 0, while the balance of USDT is 520. Were you bridging ETH and posted the wrong hash, or were you bridging USDT? | 2. Can you share the .TON address as it seems to be hashed in the transaction, and would help to see the balances there.

Did you change the network rpc on your wallet to https://bridge.ton.org and add the TON token address to your wallet?
